# Supremum of a nonempty set bounded from above is unique.

Tags: real-analysis

Proof. Let $A$ be nonempty and bounded from above. Let $s_{1}$, $s_{2}$ be two supremums of A. Since $s_{1}$ is an upper bound and $s_{2}$ is less than equal to any upper bound. We have $s_{2}\leq s_{1}$.
   Similarly, $s_{1}\leq s_{2}$. Therefore, $s_{1}=s_{2}$.

**My question is:** in proof, ''Since $s_{1}$ is an upper bound and $s_{2}$ is less than equal to any upper bound. We have $s_{2}\leq s_{1}$'' So, why?

Comment: If $s_1$ is a supremum, it is an upper bound for $A$. $s_2$ is a supremum, so by definition, it is the least upper bound which implies $s_2\le s_1$. Now argue vice-versa and conclude $s_1\le s_2$. This shows that the supremum is unique

Comment: Okey, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

That is the definition of supremum. If $s_2$ is a supremum and $x$ is any upper bound, $s_2\le x$. Since $s_1$ is also a supremum, it must be an upper bound by definition. Hence $s_2\le s_1$

Comment: I did understand your third and fourth sentence. I think that If $s_{2}$ is a supremum and $x$ is any upper bound, then $s_{2}\leq x$. Also, if $s_{1}$ is a supremum and $x$ is any upper bound, then $s_{1}\leq x$. Hence, we cannot say $s_{2}\leq s_{1}$.

Comment: Absolutely we can. By definition, $s_1$ is an upper bound. If you can agree to this then $s_2$, being the lowest, must satisfy $s_2\le s_1$. Repeat this argument for $s_1$ to find also $s_1 \le s_2$. They must be equal then.

Answer (score 0):

My proof. Let $X$ be nonempty set bounded from above. Let $supX=x_{1}$ and $supX=x_{2}$. We need to prove that $x_{1}=x_{2}$.

Let $b$ be any upper bound of $A$. We know that $x_{1}$ is least upper bound of $X$ then $x_{1}\leq b$. Also, note that $x_{2}$ is least upper bound of $X$ then $x_{2}\leq b$.

Now, since $x_{1}$ is least upper bound of $X$ then $x_{1}\leq x_{2}\leq b$. Also, since $x_{2}$ is least upper bound of $X$ then $x_{2}\leq x_{1}\leq b$. Hence, $x_{1}=x_{2}$.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: The argument is good. You don't need the b, but it isn't wrong to have it.